# Create a program that will continuously accept number when user does not input same number as the previous inputted number

Tags: java, loops

This is the only program that i can't create. Please help me with this.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    int i = 0, j=0;
     do {
         System.out.print("Enter number: ");
         i = input.nextInt();

         i=j;
     }

     while (i == j);
     System.out.println("You have inputted the same number on the previous.");

}
```

Comment: what exactly isn't working?

Comment: is this programming assignment?

Answer (score 0):

Cheers m8, good luck at your test :D

```
  public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        int i = 0, j = 999999, input = 0;
         do {
             i = j;
             System.out.print("Enter number: ");
             input = input.nextInt();

             j=input;
         } while (i != j);
         System.out.println("You have inputted the same number on the previous.");

    }
```

Comment: You shouldn't solve people homework xD :)

Comment: We all know the problem :D. If you passed the test, mark the answer as resolved

Comment: Thank you! I'm not letting people do my homework. I'm just asking for help. I'm having a hard time to think what's the logic behind this activity though it's basic. Hehehe. Again thanks buddy! I will exempt on my midterm :D

Comment: Can you accept the answer as solution please. thx ;)